# Permission issues when saving in /usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0/styles

Tags: permissions

When I try to save a file in /usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0/styles I get a window telling that the file cannot be saved because I can't change the contents of that folder.

When I right-click on the styles folder and go to permissions tab I come to know that the I am not the owner and thus cannot change these permissions. Here is a screenshot of this window:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to edit those files, besides if you upgrade gtksourceview, your changes might get lost.

In order to make changes of your own, create the folder `~/.local/share/gtksourceview-3.0/styles`:

```
mkdir  ~/.local/share/gtksourceview-3.0/styles
```

then copy the file you are interested in modifying:

```
cp /usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0/styles/cobalt.xml  ~/.local/share/gtksourceview-3.0/styles
```

(You can run these commands from the terminal. If you are using Gedit, the correct folder might be `~/.local/share/gedit/styles`.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use elevated privileges to modify files you don't own. So, instead of `gedit filename`, you'd use `gksudo gedit filename`. Or, instead of `nano filename`, you'd use `sudo nano filename`. Similarly, instead of `mv`, you'd need `sudo mv`.

Of course, you should be sure want to modify something that isn't in your home directory. And even if you're sure, make a backup for safety.